# Im trying to loose weight in my thighs but im gaining alot of muscle in them and its making them bigger

Tags: cardio, training, abdominals, legs

Im a female,16, and i weigh about 130. Im trying to loose weight in my legs but im gaining so much muscle in them that they will not slim down, its like that fat turned into muscle and i dont know how to loose it.

Comment: How tall are you for 130? Why do you think you need to lose weight? Oh, and spot reduction is a myth. You can't control where your body stores/uses fat. If your legs were the first place to accumulate fat, they will be the last places to slim down.

Comment: Have you measured your thighs?  This might be a self-image problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply keep at it and make sure you aren't eating more in response to your exercise routine.

Most likely though the muscles in your thighs have to get used to being used and [will build up to](http://www.shape.com/weight-loss/weight-loss-strategies/help-why-does-my-workout-cause-weight-gain) [a certain point](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/health-fitness/exercise/why-exercise-can-cause-weight-gain). You're also unlikely to see much weight loss at this point. The good news is once you do lose weight, you'll have great thighs.

Alternately, since you can't spot burn fat, you can focus on a full body workout to lessen the amount of muscle growth on your thighs, instead increasing muscle across your entire body, which will increase you're body's ability to burn fat.